# Deploying task definition and code with circleci

Tags: amazon-web-services, circleci, aws-code-deploy, circleci-2.0

I want to have a a ECS task definition together with my project i source control. Then i want CircleCi to deploy the task definition to my aws account then deploy the project with the new task definition.

I know circleci has AWS code deploy, which makes it easy to deploy the project, but is it possible to deploy task definitions there or any other infrastructure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You'd write the Bash commands using the AWS CLI just like you would on your local machine, but in `.circleci/config.yml` instead.